# How do I use UIApplicationDelegate throughout the program?

Tags: iphone, uiapplicationdelegate

I want to know when the status bar changes height as a result e.g. of a phone call in progress.  So I put the following in my UIApplicationDelegate:

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application willChangeStatusBarFrame:(CGRect)newStatusBarFrame {
    NSLog(@"yup, got here");
}
```

and indeed when I toggle the in-call status bar on the simulator from any screen in the application, the message appears in the console, but what I want to do is to move a uitextfield or 2 in another class since the double-height status bar is messing up one screen in particular.  I've had no luck with autoresizing on this screen.

So my question is how do I go about implementing code for one screen and one screen only from this method in the AppDelegate?  It fires in all screens but I only need it in one.  Ideally I'd like a method only in the one class to fire.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The system will also post a `UIApplicationWillChangeStatusBarFrameNotification` at the same time. Have your view controller listen to this notification. No need to mess with the app delegate at all.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll give it a try.  So I don't even need the method in the app delegate.  Great!

Answer (score 1):

Go with Ole's answer, but for future reference, how you get to your delegate is:

```
MyAppDelegate *delegate = (MyAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
```